# Get text from multiple cells of another sheet into 1 cell

Tags: google-sheets

I know how to get text from 1 cell on another sheet into another sheets' cell.
But I can't seem to find a way to get text from 2 cells of another sheet into another sheets' cell.

I use the current formula to get 1 text from 1 cell:

```
=HLOOKUP($C$1;Rooster!$1:29;27;FALSE)
```

The cell on the other sheet (Rooster) are below each other.

An example sheet (editable):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Eyb9C-O9d-Fjd5jbdGb1T23lWRyCDu0tUY9dGC63UU/edit

**Clarifying issue**

We have schedule (unfortunately I can't share the original one), but in that schedule, there are 2 fields, in 2 rows.

I can get the value from one of the fields using the above function (field is coming from index 27). Now what I want to do is getting values from both fields (indexes 27 and 28) and add them to a single field (separated by a comma).

I tried the following codes, but they do not work:

```
=HLOOKUP($C$1;Rooster!$1:29;{27,28};FALSE)
```

Or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP($C$1;Rooster!$1:29;{27,28};FALSE))
```

Or even:

```
={HLOOKUP($C$1;Rooster!$1:29;27;FALSE),=HLOOKUP($C$1;Rooster!$1:29;28;FALSE)}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: please share a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform) with example of your data and desired result.

Comment: Please ensure that your question has well-defined inputs, desired outputs, and the requirements that explain their relations. A text-based example, such as sharing an editable example sheet could be a good start.

Comment: @z.. hereby a sample link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Eyb9C-O9d-Fjd5jbdGb1T23lWRyCDu0tUY9dGC63UU/edit

Comment: @udarts, cell C1 is empty so we have no data to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out, using the ARRAYFORMULA works, but I was using a comma instead of a semicolon.

I am now using it as followed (comma separated the values):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(", ";HLOOKUP($C$1;Rooster!$1:29;{27;28};FALSE)))
```